# Zebra LP2844 not printing BarCode

Tags: java, zebra-printers

When sending the print JOB using SimpleDoc it only feeds the label but do not print it. Here is part of my code so far. I had try to changing BarCode Types and so on.

Here below is the code im trying to use to print.

```
private void printBarCode() {
        StringBuilder eti = new StringBuilder();
        String numeracion = "1234567890";
        eti.append("B")// comando para texto ASCII
                .append("2")//P1 posición x
                .append(",")
                .append("2")//P2 posición y
                .append(",")
                .append("0") //P3 rotación
                .append(",")
                .append("3")//P4 BarCode Type
                .append(",")
                .append("10") //P5 Narrow Bar width (2,3,4)
                .append(",")
                .append("Y") //P6 Wide Bar width (N)
                .append(",")
                .append("12")// P7 BarCode Heigth in dots..
                .append(",")
                .append("B") //P8 Human Readable Code B=y N=n
                .append(",")
                .append("\"")// Abre Comillas
                .append(numeracion)// DATA para Codigo de Barras
                .append("\"\n");// cierra comillas y salto de linea.

        int copias = 1;
        eti.append("P")// comando Imprimir 'P'
                .append(copias)// número de copias
                .append("\n");// salto de linea
        // pasamos el string a una matriz de bytes.
        byte[] barcodeBytes = eti.toString().getBytes();
        // imprimimos la etiqueta.
        printBarCode(barcodeBytes);
    }

private void printBarCode(byte[] datos) {

        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        Doc doc;
        doc = new SimpleDoc(datos, DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE, null);
        for (PrintService impresora : services) {
            if (impresora.getName().contains("LP 2844")) {
                DocPrintJob pj = impresora.createPrintJob();
                try {
                    pj.print(doc, null);
                } catch (PrintException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString(),
                            "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this (printing is a complex thing and I'm no expert in it) but I think you're mixing paradigms. afaik the Java print api is for postscript/pdf printers. Your Zebra printer is not such a beast. afaics it uses EPL/ZPL/CPCL. You might need to use a serial or usb interface for your commands to work